# How can I get the bookmark icon in chrome?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

when I use:

```
<img src="chrome://favicon/http://www.google.com.hk"/>
```

in my extension.It got something wrong.It warned

"Not allowed to load local resource:chrome://favicon/http://www.google.com.hk"

How can I fix it?

Comment: Why don't you simply add this image as a resource in your extension ? If necessary you then could call it with chrome.extension.getURL.

Comment: Different people have different bookmarks.How can I get all images?"www.googel.com" is just an example.I want other icon too.

Comment: You mean you want to fetch the favicon of a specific URL ?

Comment: If so, you may try to fetch http://thedomain.com/favicon.ico after having checked if the page contains something like this : <link rel="icon"  type="image/png" href="../favicon.png"/>. I don't post it as an answer through, as I guess you'd prefer a more robust solution. That's just my 2 cents...

Comment: I think fetching it from local maybe faster and what I need is just what local have.I have seen someone uses like that perfectly.So I wanna know why doesn't it work here?

Answer (score 5):

Double-check to make sure you've added the `"chrome://favicon/"` [permission](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/manifest.html#permissions).

Is this a `"manifest_version" : 2` extension? I'm not familiar with them, but they may require that you specify a [Content Security Policy](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy.html) that allows this.

Comment: I do have added the permission.I've found that this can be used only in popup.html or others that belong to the extension.But I want to put it into current page by using JS.

Comment: @Tom: Well yeah, any element belonging to a page has the page's permissions. But an XMLHttpRequest from the content script, or an iframe displaying a page from your extension, might be able to retrieve that favicon. Maybe.

Answer (score 4):

I met the same problem. I tried and see that chrome://favicon/  only work with extension own pages such as popup or tabs your extension created. It doesn't work if you load it in the normal tabs from injected content script.

There are several ways if you want to load favicon from injected content script

1. The first ones is to use request to some sevices to get favicon of a web. For an example: http://www.google.com/s2/favicons?domain=https://stackoverflow.com/
   This way works fine except the content script is injected in pages which are loading via https. The reason is due to [Mixed Content blocking](https://wiki.millersville.edu/display/d2ldocs/Understanding+mixed+content)
2. The second ones is to load favicon in background from chrome://favicon/ then transfer to content script.

Example: This function is used to run in background script

```
function fetchFavicon(url) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        var img = new Image();
        img.onload = function () {
            var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
            canvas.width =this.width;
            canvas.height =this.height;

            var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
            ctx.drawImage(this, 0, 0);

            var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
            resolve(dataURL);
        };
        img.src = 'chrome://favicon/' + url;
    });
}
```

I'm using this way for my extension, and it's working fine. Please take a look at [Super Focus Tabs](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/super-focus-tabs/blecebkjfbkpannnmajllilknpccheak) extension.

Answer (score 3):

Had the same issue, found out after searching on [google developers site](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/permission_warnings#nowarning) that you need to add a permission to the `chrome://favicon/` in the `manifest.json`.

Then just go to `chrome://extensions` and press the reload to read manifest changes.

> Note: the trailing slash is important!

Answer (score 3):

Since MV3, you can no longer use `chrome://favicon/`. Instead you need the new [Favicon Permission](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/favicon/):

## Add `favicon` to your permission

```json
{
  "name": "Favicon API in a popup",
  "manifest_version": 3,
  ...
  "permissions": ["favicon"],
  ...
}
```

## Access the favicon URL

For my simple case:

```js
const favIconUrl = `chrome-extension://${chrome.runtime.id}/_favicon/?pageUrl=${encodeURIComponent(url)}&size=32`;
```

From their example:

```js
function faviconURL(u) {
  const url = new URL(chrome.runtime.getURL("/_favicon/"));
  url.searchParams.set("pageUrl", u);
  url.searchParams.set("size", "32");
  return url.toString();
}

const img = document.createElement('img');
img.src = faviconURL("https://www.google.com") 
document.body.appendChild(img);
```

**Note:** when fetching favicons in content scripts, the "_favicon/*" folder must be declared as a web accessible resource. For example:

```json
  "web_accessible_resources": [
    {
      "resources": ["_favicon/*"],
      "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
      "extension_ids": ["*"]
    }
  ]
```