# How can I set the favicon of a bookmark through the chrome.bookmark api?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, bookmarks

I'm importing bookmarks through my chrome extension and I want to set the favicon of each bookmark.

I can't find any way of doing this in [the docs](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/bookmarks). The [`BookmarkTreeNode`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/bookmarks#type-BookmarkTreeNode) type doesn't seem to have an icon property

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I get the bookmark icon in chrome?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10301636/how-can-i-get-the-bookmark-icon-in-chrome)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you cannot change a favicon through the [`chrome.bookmarks`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/bookmarks) API.
There is a feature request at [crbug.com/59519](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=59519) though.

Answer (score 0):

I guess we can forget about this feature ever being there.
I don't like this, since the bookmark manager actually shows favIcons, but I guess we cannot.
There's something else you can do, which is to store the favIcon url as a bookmark itself. Then you can retrieve the bookmark favIcon based on the domain.

Very tiring process though.